# Should I avoid `startActivity` outside an Activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, design-patterns, workflow

I've been avoiding calling the [`startActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) method outside a `class` that `extends Activity`.

However now I have a function which handles [`401 Unauthorized`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) errors by [`putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) on an [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to pass along the error, and a `startActivity` transitioning to my Login/Register Activity.

This function sits in my `utils` module, in its own `class`.

Should I instead be returning—from this utility function—a struct of something like `(err, result, route)`, and handling that state transitioning logic in my `Activity` extending class?

EDIT: On that note, I haven't been passing around elements like [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), for a utility method to [`setText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) upon. Instead I return `String` and assign it in the `class` that `extends Activity`.

**So generally, is it bad practice to do things which affect the view/routing outside Activities?**

Comment: As long you have available access to context you can use `startActivity` anywhere.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I know I can start it outside, and I have been passing [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) around. What I want to know is is it bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can call startActivity outside the Activity subclass. As long as you have access to context reference you can call startActivity. In your case either keep a reference of Activity in util class or pass the data back to activity using the interface.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I know I can start it outside, and I have been passing [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) around. What I want to know is is it bad practice to do so?

Comment: not a bad practice. You can call startActivity outside Activity subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a bad practice. You can startActivity outside of any class. Just need to be sure about your activity stack. In case of 401 you will obviously clear stack which results in no harm to activity stack. In other cases just be confident about activity stack.